# Colour in illustrator is only bright when selected

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, rgb

I have pasted some gaussian blurs that i created in another illustrator file to this file, but for some reason the colours are very blurred and only bright when i select them with my mouse - how do i get them to be the regular brightness that they are when selected? Photos included below (first one is when selected, second shows dullness when just sitting in the document).

Thanks

Comment: Hi Welcome to GDSE. What photos?  Here's a guess. Are you in isolation mode, inside a group perhaps?  If so, double click on a blank area of the page to exit isolation mode. Share a screenshot, not a photo.

Comment: You forgot to add any images.